# Self-dual Orlicz sequence spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose that $\ell_\phi$ is a reflexive Orlicz sequence space such that its dual space $\ell_\phi^*$ is isomorphic to $\ell_\phi$.

Is $\ell_\phi$ isomorphic to $\ell_2$?

Comment: I would try to prove that if $1<p<2$ and $q$ is the conjugate index to $p$, then there is an Orlicz sequence space $X$ that is complementably universal for all Orlicz sequence spaces that are $p$ convex and $q$ concave. Such an $X$ would be isomorphic to $X^*$.

Comment: Why the vote to close?

Comment: Bill's suggestion indeed works. Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri notes this in the book. See the construction in Theorem 4.b.12 and the remark after.

Comment: Although I have no recollection of it, probably I discussed this with Lindenstrauss and/or Tzafriri in the 1970s.

Comment: Is there a Banach space $X$  with a symmetric basis $(e_n, e_n^*)$, non-equivalent to an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space, s.t. the map $e_n\mapsto e_n^*$ extends to an isomorphism from $X$ onto $X^*$?

Comment: Nice question. I think that would characterize Hilbert space. Since we have symmetric basis it is sufficient to show that every block basis is complemented. Then by Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri (the result is: if every block basis of every permutation of of unconditional basis is complemented then the basis is equivalent to uvb of $c_0$ or $\ell_p$) it has to be $\ell_2$. If $(x_n)$ is a normalized block basis, $x_n=\sum_{i\in F_n} a_i e_i$ then by the isomorphism $\|x^*_n=\sum_{F_n}a_i e^*_i\|\le C$. Then the projection $Px=\sum_n x^*_n(x)x_n$ is bounded.

Comment: Indeed, if $x=\sum_i b_i e_i$, then after some calculation $Px$ becomes $\sum_n \left(\sum_{i\in F_n}a^2_ib_i\right) e_i$. So its norm is less than $C\|\sum_n (\max_{i\in F_n}b_i)e_i\|$ since $\sum_{F_n}a^2_i\le C$. And the last expression is less than $C\|x\|$ by symmetry.

Comment: @Bunyamin: But the $x_n^*$ are not a priori biorthogonal to $x_n$. You don't know that $\langle x_n^*, x_n \rangle =\sum_{I\in F_n} a_n^2$ is bounded away from zero unless you assume what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @Bunyamin: I guess you do get a lower $\ell_2$ estimate, which also gives an upper $\ell_2$ estimate in view of the isomorphism hypothesis, and thus the symmetric basis is equivalent to the $\ell_2$ unit vector basis. No Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri theorem is needed.

Comment: @Bill. Yes, that's right, no reason for them to be biorthogonal.  I should have seen the simple lower estimate argument!

Comment: @Bunyamin: You should make your first comment an answer so that Manuel can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a given $1<p$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ you can construct a *universal* Orlicz sequence space $\ell_M$ so that every Orlicz function $N$ *in between* $p$ and $q$ is equivalent to a function in $E_M$ which corresponds to the Orlicz subspaces spanned by constant block bases of $\ell_M$ thus complemented. Such a space is unique up to isomorphism (depending only to $p$), and $E_{M^*}$ has the same property so $\ell_{M^*}$ is isomorphic to $\ell_{M}$ by the uniqueness. This construction is given in [LT, Theorem 4.b.12]. See also the remark after.

This answer was first given by Bill Johnson in comments, I just added the reference.

*Lindenstrauss, Joram; Tzafriri, Lior*, Classical Banach spaces. 1: Sequence spaces. 2. Function spaces., Classics in Mathematics. Berlin: Springer-Verlag. xx, 432 p. (1996). [ZBL0852.46015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0852.46015).